# O que é reflection?

Tags: reflexão

Estamos a criar um site sobre a historia informática dos anos 70 ate 90, e a um certo ponto encontrei o paradigma `reflective`. Tem este ultima alguma a coisa a ver com `reflection`, que já agora o que é?

Comment: Pode ser o que diz a descrição da tag ou pode ser outra coisa, é meio amplo sem detalhes.

Comment: Reflexão (C# e Visual Basic) http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173183.aspx

Comment: Reflexão é um paradigma na programação. Tem mais sobre isto [neste artigo da Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflex%C3%A3o_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)). Mais tarde posso dar uma resposta mais elaborada.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Visão geral

Reflexão é a capacidade de um programa saber **de que partes ele próprio é composto**, sem necessitar que para isso o programador tenha de inserir esses dados manualmente, ou seja, os dados sobre a estrutura do programa são inseridos e produzidos automaticamente pelo compilador na forma de **meta-dados**.

É como se fosse um espelho, por isso se chama reflexão: o programa vê a si próprio... ele têm conhecimento de suas características: quais classes existem, quais métodos existem, etc..

## Paradigma reflexivo

A reflexão trata também, por extensão, da capacidade que alguns programas possuem de alterar a si próprios, ou seja, de adicionarem mais código a si próprio de forma dinâmica, constituindo dessa forma, um paradigma através do qual se pode programar.

Ou seja, é o paradigma que permite meta-programação, ou seja, além de permitir a observação dos meta-dados, permite a geração de novas partes para o programa de forma dinâmica, ou até mesmo a substituição de partes existentes por outras geradas dinamicamente.

Portanto, o paradigma reflexivo tem relação com a reflexão.

**Paradigma reflexivo == Meta-programação**

### As aplicações são muitas

- sistemas de plug-in: a reflexão permite buscar as classes que implementam funcionalidades adicionais dentro de um pacote
- ampliação das capacidades da linguagem: containers de IoC geralmente usam reflexão para criar objetos, frameworks de mocking também, programação orientada a aspectos, entre tantos outros.
- programação genética: é um método de criar programas de forma dinâmica, para resolver problemas específicos, baseado na ideia evolução que imita a que acontece com os genes
- auto-otimização: permite que um programa se adapte à forma a qual é utilizado a nível de código

Comment: @Broly sim. Vide [este wiki](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflex%C3%A3o_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)#Paradigma_reflexivo).